# How do I move the TOC to the beginning?

Tags: table-of-contents

Can you please review my main `.tex` file and help me to find which line I should replace to get the table of contents from after the fourth chapter to before the summary (named "sommario").

Here is my example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\begin{document}
\include{frontespizio}
\thispagestyle{empty} \normalfont \cleardoublepage
\include{dedica}
\thispagestyle{empty}  \cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\include{sommario}
\thispagestyle{empty} \vspace*{.75truecm} \cleardoublepage
\include{ringraziamenti}
\thispagestyle{empty} \vspace*{.75truecm} \normalfont \cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{plain}\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}} 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}         
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}    

\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}    
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}     
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt} 

\include{capitolo1}
\include{capitolo2}
\include{capitolo3}
\include{capitolo4}

\appendix

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyfoot{}                                               
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\appendixname\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}} 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}         
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}    

\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}    
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}     
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt} 

\renewcommand\bibname{references}
\tableofcontents\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}\newpage
\renewcommand\listfigurename{list of figures}\listoffigures
\renewcommand\listtablename{list of tables}\listoftables

%\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{list of symbols}\input{FrontMat/Symbols}

%\include{appendiceA}
%\include{appendiceB}
%\include{appendiceC}
%\include{appendiceD}
%\include{appendiceE}
%\include{appendiceF}
\cleardoublepage
% ---- Bibliography ----
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografy}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{refs}
\nocite{*}
\include{refs}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Moving  `\tableofcontents` command before `\include{sommario}` ?

Comment: Did the comment by @fran help you, so we cant write an answer to the question?

Comment: @Fran Please make that an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: The Table of Contents is placed where is the control the control sequence (command) `\tableofcontents`, so simply move that control sequence where the Contents must be showed.

**Long answer**:

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\date{Moving date (down)}
\author{The author}
\title{Moving Title (up)}

\maketitle

\begin{figure}
\fbox{a moving figure to the bottom}    
\end{figure}

\section{A section} This is a section\footnote{note moving to the end of text} 

\subsection{A subsection} This is a subsection  

\tableofcontents % not moving

\section{Another section} This is another section 
\subsection{Another subsection} This is another subsection  

\end{document}
```

> [image: MWE]

When new users see how LaTeX move many text elements *automagically* just where they should be (for example a title after the author appear before in the PDF, a figure on top of the text go to the bottom, a footnote go to the eh... well, the footnote.) the song *A Spoonful Of Sugar* from Mary Poppins starts playing inside your head.

But as Poppins leave some job for the amazed children, LaTeX is not always so  *Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious*. Since users can have different thoughts with respect the right position of the *Contents*, therefore LaTeX simply respect your snap of fingers (at least in most common document classes).

In this case, the command `\tableofcontents` in the first compilation simply write the `\contentsname` with a appropriated format and spaces, but stealthily the auxiliary `.toc` file is generated, that in the above MWE look like:

```
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}A section}{1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1}A subsection}{1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}Another section}{1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.1}Another subsection}{1}
```

In the second compilation, the code of this `.toc` fle is simply  inserted after "Contents" (just like *copy & paste* these four lines at hand in the main document) but not moved to any position, so it could be placed in bizarre places as in the MWE, inside a subsection in the middle of an article.